# To define the metric in $C[0,1]$, why do we need to emphasize that continuous functions defined on a closed intervals are uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I see this below from a book on functional analysis:

> A somewhat more exotic example of a metric space is $C[0,1]$: the set
> of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Recall that continuous functions
> defined on a closed intervals are uniformly continuous. The sup metric
> is then well defined as
>
> $$d(f,g)=\sup\{ |f(t)-g(t)|:t \in [0,1]\}$$
>
> for $f,g \in C[0,1]$.

Question: here, why the book mentions / emphasizes "Recall that continuous functions defined on a closed intervals are uniformly continuous."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mentioned, because (uniformly) continuous functions defined on a compact metric space have a maximum on that set. In this case, this yields, that the metric is well defined. To be specific this implies that $d(f,g)<\infty$ for any $f,g \in C [0,1]$, which is one of the requirements for a metric.

To see that this is important consider the following: On the open intervall $(0,1)$ the function $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1/x$ is continuous, but $d(f,0) = \sup\{|f(t)| : t \in (0,1) \} = \infty$ (where $0$ is the constant $0$ function). Therefore $d$ is not a metric on $C(0,1)$.

Comment: But why does the "uniform" matter?  This seems to be about continuity on a compact set (which implies uniform, but is not needed to assure a maximum).

Comment: @Randall i think it is because it follows easily from the uniform continuity that a maximum is attained. But obviously i am not the author so i dont know for sure. Maybe they use uniform continuity explicitly further down in the text (like when they presumably show completeness).